# Anime space opera from the 80s, possibly involving some temporal paradox

Tags: story-identification, anime, space-opera

I'm trying to identify an old anime movie from my childhood. I saw it around the might-eighties.

It was a space opera, and I can recall the following elements:

- A big space fleet that is escaping their dying homeworld attacks Earth in order to conquer it.
- There might have been some time travel paradox or loop involved, like the invading fleet turning out to be from a future Earth or somesuch.
- Visual element: I believe a flashback (or perhaps a dream sequence) had a rose in it.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of Star Blazers?

Comment: Or maybe [The Super Dimension Fortress Macross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macross:_Do_You_Remember_Love%3F)

Comment: A lot of details fit the *Outlanders* anime, except the aliens aren't escaping a dying homeworld. http://www.theanimereview.com/reviews/outlanders.html

Comment: Other than the 80's part this reminds me of Martian Successor Nadesico

Comment: @Gavin In Martian Successor Nadesco, there was the big twist that the alien "Jovians" turned out to be humans who had been driven off, but it wasn't a time loop, as far as I recall. As an aside, the "it was Earth all along" thing in this question made me think of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvuM3DjvYf0&t=50s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be [*"Space Warrior Baldios"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Warrior_Baldios). It's a *series* aired in 1981, with a *movie* concluding the story released the following year.

It matches your description of a fleet coming from a dying planet: the invaders escaped their home planet, become almost uninhabitable due to radiation poisoning after a terrible war, aboard a space fortress, trying at all costs to find a new planet.

The time loop element matches too as, in order to defeat the terrestrial forces, the invading army provokes greater and greater disasters (the destruction of Mercury and Venus, the melting of Earth's polar ice caps) progressively making Earths more and more similar to their home world. In the end, it is indeed revealed that the invading fleet moved through *time* rather than *space*, and are effectively humans from the future.

I only have some vague recollection of the series and I don't have distinct memories of flashbacks, so I cannot say whether this matches the "rose sequence" or not.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm almost sure that it was this movie. The cover art for the soundtrack features the rose https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JK2doBwNhDM so it's very likely that it will be a motif within the movie itself.