# 80’s Sci-fi anime with an outside force attacking the planet resulting in space battles

Tags: story-identification, anime

- Anime film or series from the 80's.
- There is this hostile extraterrestrial force that attacks the planet.
- Action takes place in space near the planet and with spaceship battles.
- The planet sea level is rising (because of global warming?).
- At some point, someone compares the estimated landmasses with the attackers' planet resulting in a similar area, suggesting that they come from the future.

Comment: You've got a good start, but can you visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 to see if you can edit more details in?

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/224663/40711)? (though you don't mention any _giant robot_)

Comment: yes, is a duplicate