# Japanese anime OVA from 80s/70s

Tags: story-identification, anime

For my birthday in the late 80s/early 90s  we watched an OVA anime movie.  I have been trying to find it for 30 years.

It is like a combination of 3-4 genres:

- Hero is in war(nuke) ravaged future earth with this ship in space.
- He goes back in time to undo the damage.
- His ship combines with other ships in the past to create a big Voltron-like robot.
- Twist is that he ends up causing said nuclear apocalypse, the movie
  ends on a noir/tragedy note.
- I remember nukes (spherical objects) going into ice caps.

The movie could be from the early 80s maybe even 70s.

I think it was the standard like 90 minute movie format.  I think we rented it from Blockbuster at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be the [*"Space Warrior Baldios"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Warrior_Baldios) 1981 movie, which brought to a conclusion the animated series with the same name.

After a military coup the main villain has fled the planet S-1 (dying and contaminated due to radiation after a nuclear conflict) on a large flying fortress called Algol, together with the remaining population, to find a new world to live in. They arrive near Earth, and they set to conquer it.

At the end of the series, and in the movie too, both the good guys and the villains realize that the spaceship voyaged *back in time* and S-1 is just the Earth after the war they are currently fighting.
The final disaster is the melting of the ice caps at the Poles, and the subsequent tsunami, caused by nuclear explosions.

Comment: Should this be correct, the question would be a duplicate of [_"Anime space opera from the 80s, possibly involving some temporal paradox"_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/224663/40711).

Comment: Thanks, I remember the cover of the VHS and that is definitely it.