# Syfy animated film from before 1998 about people in space ships looking for a habitable planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I watched this film (I believe it was a film as I watched it in its entirety in one go so I don't think it was longer than two hours) one time around 1997/1998. I believe I saw it on MTV's Liquid Television and I believe it is Japanese. I am not looking for the 70's French film *"Fantastic Planet"*, I already checked it out, and that isn't what I remember seeing.

The story basically is people have destroyed their planet and board ships to go into space looking for a new planet to live on. I think that they no longer looked fully human.

They find a habitable planet, only to discover that they had already been there, destroyed it and left it. They had been doing that, going from planet to planet like locusts, destroying everything and moving on, so long that they had forgotten that they had originally come from Earth.
I'm not sure about this last part but there may have been beings on Earth when they return that are different, but similar enough to confirm that the travelers had once come from that planet.

Comment: [_"Space Warrior Baldios"_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Warrior_Baldios)? (in that case, this would be a duplicate of [_Anime space opera from the 80s, possibly involving some temporal paradox_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/224663/40711))

Comment: Did you check out _Space Warrior Baldios_ to confirm whether that's the film you're looking for or not? I won't link it, but it's easy to find and watch on YouTube.

Comment: Why do you describe the film as "Syfy" in the title?  That refers to a specific television network, yet you say you watched it on MTV.  Did you mean to write "Sci-fi"?